# Access to FOPs Area Tree in version 0.20.5 from java code

Tags: tree, area, apache-fop

Is it possible to have access to FOPs Area Tree in version 0.20.5 from java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though quite inactive nowadays)*

Looking at the embedding examples inside FOP 0.20.5 distribution (I don't have the source code at hand), it looks like the class `org.apache.fop.apps.Driver` has a `.setRenderer()` method; to create a *PDF*, this method is called like this:

```
driver.setRenderer(Driver.RENDER_PDF);
```

and I guess the `Driver` class has a constant for the *area tree* output too.

**However, FOP 0.20.5 is *really* old**, so I would recommend using a more recent version (2.0 has been released in June 2015).

**Using FOP 2.0**, as seen in the [embedding documentation page](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/embedding.html#basics), you can use an `org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory` to get an instance of `org.apache.fop.apps.Fop` for the required output type, in this case:

```
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_FOP_AREA_TREE, out);
```

---

The area tree output (regardless of the FOP version) is an XML file, so you can use a parser to obtain a `Document` object and **look** at the geometric properties of the areas.

Recent versions of FOP (**not** 0.20.5) allow to [use the area tree XML as **input**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/intermediate.html), to obtain (for example) a PDF output file:

1. use FOP to create the area tree XML from a source file
2. use your own code to **modify** the area tree XML
3. use FOP again to create the final output from the modified area tree XML